# New to firebase, and unsure why the "createdAt" field doesn't render in the Chat component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a web chat app with react and firebase. I'm new to the latter and I'm not sure why,  when I add documents with the attributes text, photoURL, displayName, uid and createdAt to the  messages collection, the last attribute doesn't show in the Chat component when mapping through each document.

**Chat.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Logout from './Logout';
import { auth, store } from '../firebase';
import SendMsg from './SendMsg';

const Chat = () => {
    const scroll = useRef()
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        store.collection("messages").orderBy("createdAt").limit(100).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
        })
    },[]) // no need to add messages to the second argument because onSnapshot takes care of running useEffect according to collections only
    return (
        <div>
            <Logout /> 
            <div className = "messages">
            {messages.map(({id, text, photoURL,displayName, uid, createdAt}) =>
                // unique id for each document 
                <div>
                    <div key = {id} className = {`message ${uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? "sent" : "received"}`}> 
                    {console.log(id)}
                    <img src={photoURL} alt=""/>
                    <div className="displayName">{displayName}</div>
                    <p>{createdAt}</p>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            </div>
            <SendMsg scroll={scroll} />
            <div ref={scroll}></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat;
```

**SendMsg.jsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Button, Input } from '@material-ui/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {store, auth} from "../firebase"

const SendMsg = ({scroll}) => {
const [message, setMessage] = useState(" ");

async function sendMessage(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents the send button from refreshing the page
    const {uid, photoURL, displayName}  = auth.currentUser //information about the current user
    await store.collection("messages").add({
        text: message,
        photoURL,
        displayName,
        uid,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
    setMessage('') //empty input
    scroll.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
}
return (
    <div className = "sendMessage">
        <form onSubmit = {sendMessage}>
            <Input style={{ width: '78%', fontSize: '15px', fontWeight: '550', marginLeft: '5px', marginBottom: '-3px' }} value = {message} onChange = {(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} placeholder = "Type Here!" />
            <Button style={{ width: '18%', fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: '600', margin: '4px 5% -13px 5%', maxWidth: '200px'}} type="submit">Send</Button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
}

export default SendMsg;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also somewhat new, but I use this to store a created at date:

```
firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
```

You will also want to convert it when displaying it

```
date.toDate().toDateString();
```

Edit 1: Remember to unsub your onSnapshot listener:

```
useEffect(() => {
        return store.collection("messages").orderBy("createdAt").limit(100).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
        })
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch field that is a Firestore timestamp, it'll be an object as shown:

```
{
  created: {
    seconds: 1627370100,
    nanoseconds: 0
  }
}
```

You can use [`toDate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method to convert that to a [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
console.log(createdAt) // Javascript Date object
console.log(Date.parse(createdat)) // Timestamp in milliseconds
```